# Magento Ajax Request - how to correctly pass data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, module

Since couple of weeks(two) started my adventure with Magento. So far I've learned a little but have a problem how to send data using Ajax (jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var total = $(this).find(\"input[class=tramp]:checked\").length;
        $(\".caret input[type='checkbox']\").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                var value= true;
                }else{
                    var value = false;
                }               
            var brand = $(this).data('brand');

            data = {brand: brand, value: value}
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                url: 'checkbox/ajax/index',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(data, total);
            }});
        });
```

});

This is my Ajax, so as you can see trying to send brand and value. AjaxController.php looks like this:

```
class Amber_Checkbox_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function indexAction()
{
    $brand = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('brand', 'value');// not sure or I should use data?
    if($brand )
    {
        ....
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($brand);

        echo $brand;
        ...
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

remove \"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var total = $(this).find("input[class=tramp]:checked").length;
        $(".caret input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                var value= true;
                }else{
                    var value = false;
                }               
            var brand = $(this).data('brand');

            data = {brand: brand, value: value}
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                url: 'checkbox/ajax/index',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(data, total);
            }});
        });
});
```

Comment: Hello ahhmar, In this case if I remove \" it just don't work :) so I must escape ". This part of the code works fine, I can't see anything on the ajaxController site. :(

Answer (score 0):

remove \", $ replace with **jQuery** and pass absolute URL `Mage::getUrl('checkbox/ajax/index');`

```
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("checkbox/ajax/index"); ?>',
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(result){
  console.log(data, total);
}});
```

Comment: Because this block is inserted while the series of divs is generated it won't work if there is no \" (backslash), i'll try ;)

Comment: Okay so in this case \" required

Comment: What is the difference betwieen $ and jQuery ? It does matter ?

Comment: Actually magento internally use $ sign so if you use $ then it conflict so use always use in magento jQuery instead $. both are equal.